# can't retrieve data because of 'undefined' value

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

In my website i am listing movies and tv series that users can share their comments on them. Users can add comments, but when it comes to receiving comments, an undefined value is returned. (I am trying to get comments from movieComment. movieComment store comments for the movie)

```
var show = qs["movieId"];
/* show variable is giving my movie's ID and it is 1 */
btnComment.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    var movieComment = document.getElementById('textComment').value;
    push(child(firebaseRef, 'Movies/' + show + '/movieComment/'), movieComment) {
        movieComment: movieComment
    };
});

function AddItemsToTable2(comment) {
    const comments = `
              <td>Alan Smith</td>
              <td><i class="fa fa-star" style="color:rgb(91, 186, 7)"></i></td>
              <td>${comment}<h6>[May 09, 2016]</h6></td>
            `;
    html = comments;
    body2.innerHTML += html;
}

}

function AddAllItemsToTable2(TheComments) {
    body2.innerHTML = "";
    TheComments.forEach(element => {
        AddItemsToTable2(element.movieComment);
    });
}

function getAllDataOnce2() {
    var show = qs["movieId"];
    get(child(firebaseRef, 'Movies/' + show + '/movieComment')).then((snapshot) => {
        var comments = [];
        comments.push(snapshot.val());
        console.log(comments);
        AddAllItemsToTable2(comments);

    });

}

window.onload = (event) => {
    getAllDataOnce2();

};
```

[image]

**Console.log(movies)**

[image]

**Undefined error:**

[image]

Comment: Please provide debugging information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Focusing on this function:

```js
function AddAllItemsToTable2(TheComments) {
    body2.innerHTML = "";
    TheComments.forEach(element => {
        AddItemsToTable2(element.movieComment);
    });
}
```

The `TheComments` object here is a `Record<string, string>[]`:

```js
TheComments = [{
  "-Mstwhft8fKP6-M2MRIk": "comment",
  "-Mstwj5P2TD_stgvZL8V": "a comment",
  "-MstwjxvmkNAvWFaIejp": "another comment"
}]
```

When you iterate over this array, you end up with an element object that doesn't have a `movieComment` property, which is why when you feed it to `AddItemsToTable2` you get `undefined`.

To fix this, you need to change the way you assemble the `TheComments` object:

```js
function AddAllItemsToTable2(TheComments) { // TheComments: ({id: string, text: string})[]
    body2.innerHTML = "";
    TheComments.forEach(commentObj => AddItemsToTable2(commentObj.text));
}

function getAllDataOnce2() {
    const show = qs["movieId"];
    get(child(firebaseRef, 'Movies/' + show + '/movieComment'))
        .then((snapshot) => {
            const comments = [];
            snapshot.forEach(childSnapshot => {
                comments.push({
                    id: childSnapshot.key,     // store this for linking to database/anchors
                    text: childSnapshot.val()
                });
            });
            console.log(comments);
            AddAllItemsToTable2(comments);
        });
}
```

---

As another point, beware of XSS risks when using `innerHTML` and use `innerText` where possible for any user generated content. Also, you should wrap your comment content in a table row so comments are concatenated properly.

```js
function AddItemsToTable2(commentObj) {
    const commentEle = document.createElement('span');
    commentEle.id = `comment_${commentObj.id}`;
    commentEle.innerText = commentObj.text;
    
    const commentRowHTML = `
            <tr>
              <td>Alan Smith</td>
              <td><i class="fa fa-star" style="color:rgb(91, 186, 7)"></i></td>
              <td>${commentEle.outerHTML}<h6>[May 09, 2016]</h6></td>
            </tr>`;
    body2.innerHTML += commentRowHTML;
}

function AddAllItemsToTable2(TheComments) {
    body2.innerHTML = "";
    TheComments.forEach(commentObj => AddItemsToTable2(commentObj));
}
```

With the above code block, you can now add `#comment_-MstwjxvmkNAvWFaIejp` to the end of the current page's URL to link to the "another comment" comment directly similar to how StackOverflow links to comments.